# Having trouble storing string inside an array of C struct

Tags: c

Hey I'm simply trying to store a string inside of a struct so i can call on it later in printf's. For some reason it doesn't store the string or print it. What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct receipt
{
  char burger_type[45];
};
struct receipt r[25];
int main()
{  
  r[1].burger_type == "chicken Burger";
  
  printf("%s pls work",r[1].burger_type);

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you too anyone who can help.
Thanks

Comment: You do know `r[0].burger_type = "chicken Burger";` would be the first element in the array? (arrays are **zero based** in C) You also know you are not storing `"chicken Burger"` in the array and you need to use `strcpy()` to copy the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison) is the equality operator. For assignment you use the [`=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment) assignment operator.

Regardless of that, you cannot assign a value of type `const char *` to a `char [45]`. Use [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to place the value of that string in your destination.

```
strcpy(r[1].burger_type, "chicken Burger");
```

When using these functions, you must be cautious that the size of your input does not exceed the size of your destination.

You should turn up the warnings on your compiler to catch these kinds of malformed code (e.g., `gcc -Wall ...`).

Comment: Do note that there's a case where `strncpy` will not add the string null-terminator. When using `strncpy` always make sure to add it.

Comment: Best to use `strcpy()` instead (especially if the destination array is large)